# ¿Existe algun limite para cantidad de elementos en un NOT IN en firebird 2.5? SQL Error -104 unexpected end of command

Tags: sql, firebird

Buen día tengo un problema en una consulta generada por un procedimiento en pascal. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
Select CodigoProveedor as Codigo 
From proveedores 
where Activo = 1
And CodigoProvedores not in (....aca hay muchos strings)
--y a su vez hay muchos NOT IN por una cuestion de lectura
```

Y me arroja el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo pienso que el motor esperaba un espacio o un ;, dado el largo de la consulta y por eso me arroja el error, pero la verdad ni idea. Si me pueden dar una mano se los agradeceria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para lo que existe un límite es para el tamaño de una sentencia SQL, este [FAQ de firebird](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq197/#:%7E:text=Yes.,to%2010MB%20as%20a%20precaution.) (en inglés) dice:

> ### Is there a limit to SQL statement size?
>
> Yes. Applications using Firebird 3.0 API and above have the limit of 10MB. The engine itself can support up to 4GB, but the size is limited to 10MB as a precaution.
>
> Earlier versions of Firebird API have a limit of 64kB (65536 characters in a single-byte character set). Also, the BLR that comes out as a result must also fit into 64kB. If you don't know what BLR is, read FAQ #187. Additionally, the query plan has to fit in 48kB.

Mi traducción libre es (el énfasis es mío):

> ### ¿Existe un límite para el tamaño de la instrucción SQL?
>
> Si. Las aplicaciones que utilizan la API de Firebird 3.0 y superior tienen un límite de 10 MB. El motor en sí puede admitir hasta 4 GB, pero el tamaño está limitado a 10 MB como precaución.
>
> Las versiones anteriores de la API de Firebird **tienen un límite de 64 kB (65536 caracteres en un conjunto de caracteres de un solo byte)**. Además, el BLR que sale como resultado también debe caber en 64kB. Si no sabe qué es BLR, lea la pregunta frecuente n. ° 187. Además, el plan de consulta debe caber en 48kB.

Es probable que IBExpert (que está hecho en Delphi) esté pasando la sentencia en UTF16, así que eso reduciría el límite a solo 32767 caracteres.

Una posible alternativa, dado lo que buscas hacer, es que tengas una [tabla temporal](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-table.html) en la cual deposites todos los datos del not in y re-escribas tu consulta para tirar de dicha tabla:

```
create global temporary table TempCodigoExcluir (
  codigo varchar(32)
)
on commit delete rows;
```

Ir insertando en esta tabla los registros a excluir:

```
insert into TempCodigoExcluir values ('30-60155401-8');
insert into TempCodigoExcluir values ('30-60163789-4');
-- y así ir insertando los códigos que quieres excluir
```

Para finalmente:

```
select *
  from MiTabla
 where CodigoProveedor not in (select Codigo from TempCodigoExcluir)
```

Comment: Es una excelente solución. Tenia esta duda porque con otros motores de BD que he trabajado no tuve problemas. Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Todos tienen un límite, quizás no es tan bajo y por eso no te lo has topado. Si trabajaras con versiones recientes de Firebird, como ves en mi respuesta, el límite sería mucho más grande, por lo que seguro tampoco te daría problema.